# HTML5+CSS3+JS framework?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I'm looking for a framework to carry out part of my PFC. I have an application in android development that will display information on mobile.

Now, I want to develop a backend to manage that information. The idea is as follows:

- Choose a framework html5 + css3 + one type jquery javascript framework / ui / etc.
- I want the backend to manage things offline:
  creating data
  data modification
  confirmation and upload data to the server (the latter through an api that I have created: Java based Jersey, restful web service using Json).

All this I would do it with the sql support that has html5. Also I want to use many options such as geolocation and so on.
- Management online:
Online data Modification: connection to the server using the api, data visualization, and to modify them.

- I wish this would work standalone backend: run without a server (actually if loging is needed for a first time and functions online, but the idea is to be offline most of the management), alike a desktop application.

That in a nutshell is what I do. At first it seems little, but it will take my time. Anyway, I hope not to overdo too.

The question is, do you know any framework (if it can be called framework) that enables me to do this? (And if they can add me some style, buttons, icons, fonts...) If possible agile development because they do not want to linger long with this.

Thank you!

P.S.: it would be wonderful to be responsive and multiplatform (different layouts for desktop, tablet, smartphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to use BOOTSTRAP.